# How do I pronounce 0x10c?

Tags: 0x10c

There's been some debate about how to pronounce the title for Notch's newest game, 0x10<sup>c</sup>. Notch knows but apparently it's ["a riddle"](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/187266546681393153) and he's not telling yet. I've heard that it's related to the programming error that the plot employs to explain the 16-bit CPUs in the far future but I don't know the details.

Comment: It's trying to be a Hexadecimal number but that's not a logical Hex number due to the odd number of digits. Here's some background on Hex's pronunciation http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/107479/pronunciation-for-hexadecimals

Comment: @Decency because hex is always a representation of binary, so anything but a binary exponent's worth of digits in hex doesn't make any sense

Comment: I've heard, "Zero x TEN c[soft c]", i.e., "Zero Existence"

Comment: Heh heh. Extenze.

Comment: @BenBrocka - To be fair, base 16 is a valid numeral system to be formatted exactly like you would any other number base.  The Unix derivative "0x" style formulation is convenient for computing use, so it's pretty much all you see these days, and it's really the only version that's relevant given that this game is largely about programming, but as a pedant I feel the need to state that sometimes a number in hexadecimal is just a number in hexadecimal.

Comment: It'd be my recommendation that you take out the first paragraph. It doesn't add much to the question, talking about rep doesn't usually help, and it's doing good so far. :)

Comment: @Ullallulloo Makes sense. I thought I'd get more resistance.

Comment: @authenticgeek: Unlike Skyrim, this is actually really confusing. :P

Comment: Well, the value of 0x10<sup>C</sup> is 281,474,976,710,656. Doesn't really roll off the tongue..

Comment: Well, it's a game about assembly programming, so I think it's fair to say any hex involved is computing related...like 99.9% of all uses of hex ever.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out http://0x10c.wonderhowto.com/forum/pronounce-0x10c-2075/

there seems to be a lot of discussion as to what it could mean. some answers are below.

hex sixteen c

Zero X

0 to warp speed, considering both 0 and 10^c to be speed notation where c is the constant value for the speed of light… making 10^c some sort of superluminal speed.

Sixteen

Finally, Notch actually confirmed how to pronounce it: https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/187274697799499777

**“Ten to the c”**

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I found [this place](http://0x10c.wonderhowto.com/forum/pronounce-0x10c-2075/) to be most informative within the first 3 posts. Just skip the 2nd one anyway ;) I personally would pronounce it like the math problem way, but I really like 0 XD and since I program, I get the hexadecimal numeral thing (I was actually just reading about them the other day! Freaky...).

It really kind of is opinion until they tell us. I feel they will say it the hexadecimal numeral way. And, I like this actually so even though I'd generally down vote something like this, I'ma swing you an up vote ;) Thanks for bringing this up :) I look forward to following this.

Comment: Ben I think you have edited about half my responses XD Ok, maybe its just 3... but it feels like more, because some we've both answered, some I answered yours, and some you edited mine. So I bet more than half my responses you are in someway associated with XD Yes I know this isn't a good comment... Can't help it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Notch, as seen on ["The Shaft" episode 100](http://www.theshaftpodcast.com/2012/09/the-shaft-100-notch.html), stated it was pronounced "Ten to C."

Comment: A link to this episode would help back up your answer.

Comment: Additionally, your answer essentially restates an existing (and accepted) answer.  You can add more detail to that answer by editing it.